# pymongo query using date range

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have mongodb collection named jobs, having

```
{"_id":  "1", "jobUploadDate":  "2017-02-01T14:30:57.361Z"}, 
{"_id":  "2", "jobUploadDate":  "2017-02-02T14:31:26.497Z"},
{"_id":  "3", "jobUploadDate":  "2017-02-03T15:04:45.064Z"}
```

am using pymongo, to find the jobs between two dates

```
def find_jobs(self,from_date,to_date):
    to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, "%Y%m%d").isoformat()
    from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, "%Y%m%d").isoformat()
    query = {}
    query['jobUploadDate'] = {'$lte': to_date,'$gte':from_date}

    #self.db = .....get mongodb connection and 

    jobs_found = self.db.jobs.find(query, {
        '_id': 1,
        'jobUploadDate': 1})

    return dumps(list(jobs_found))

print(find_jobs("20170202","20170202"))
```

I am expecting the output following, but it returns NO results.

```
{"_id":  "2", "jobUploadDate":  "2017-02-02T14:31:26.497Z"}
```

How to project "jobUploadDate" to date and strip time and compare?

Answer (score 0):

The date format you use to strip datetime assigns zero time to the date, test this:

```
dstring = "20170202"
d = datetime.strptime(dstring, "%Y%m%d")
print(d)

2017-02-02 00:00:00
```

so you should call `find_jobs("20170202","20170203")` for the range of one day that you want.